# Resources ids not updating in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I recently updated to Android Studio 3.0 and noticed that when I for example add any android:id, or create new drawable, or basically any resource, Android Studio does not update it in project until I build application. Every resource I create in xml, in class is marked as red and standard "Cannot resolve symbol ..." is shown. But surprisingly if you try to go to declaration, it correctly goes to the resource. Is there any option for this not to happen? 
It's very irritating.

---

Edit:
It's still occuring sometimes, but I just got used to it. If someone fixed it I will be thankful for your answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, do you resolve it? please share your result and i appreciate it

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: i'm also facing same problem

Comment: facing this issue sometimes, frustrate of it

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem in this way:

Navigate to Android Studio Settings - Build,Execution,Deployment - Gradle

Choose "Use local gradle distribution" and "Offline work", click "Apply"

At last you'll find it's ok, and at this time you can also choose back to "use  default gradle wrapper", it's normal

Comment: Also I don't have this option enabled, it's only `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`.

Comment: After further inspection I noticed I am not having this error anymore, so maybe changes you mentioned I made unpurposely. For now I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: this option is hidden  by default so what should I do now ??

Comment: i'm also facing same problem

Comment: I had to unmark it as the answer because it's still occuring sometimes, I just gave up for now. Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Comment: ok. i already have the above settings but issue exists. Also i am not sure why the above changes would fix this. what we need is some action like "autocompile resource file on change"  to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart